# Create Javascript object from Keys arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, pojo

I'm struggling with an operation I can't achieve, I have a number of arrays like these:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
['key1', 'key2', 'key4']
['key1', 'key5']
```

For each of this array there is a corresponding value:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

I want to create an empty object from each array, that has an hierarchy based on the keys position in the array, for example:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] => { key1: { key2: { key3: value1 } } }
```

And at the end, merge these objects and build an object that is as this:

```
var object = {
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: value1,
            key4: value2
        },
        key5: value3
    }
}
```

I tried some approaches but they require three for loops iterations and I think there is a better way for doing this, of course the merge at the end is the easiest part, I can just user the jQuery merge to do so, but I'm really struggling on create the single object from each array.

Thank you very much, if you need any more information let me know.

Cheers

Comment: How do the `value1`, `value2` etc variables relate to the arrays? Seeing some code you've written would help a lot here, as we need to see the context of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because this returns the object you need, without keeping a reference outside.

```js
function set(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var a = {};

set(a, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 'value1'); 
set(a, ['key1', 'key2', 'key4'], 'value2'); 
set(a, ['key1', 'key5'], 'value3'); 

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function create(arr, value, o = {}) {
  a = o;
  // loop trough the object
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // add a new object with the name of an array object
    a[arr[i]] = {};
    // important step: move the pointer `a` deeper into the object...
    a = a[arr[i]];
  }
  // set the last object's value to the passed value
  a.value = value;
  return o;
}
```

Use like this:

```
var object = create(["a", "b", "c"], true);
object2 = create(["d", "e", "f"], true, object);
```

Comment: Please explain your code. SO is to help everyone learn not code for others